# Purchasing travel insurance while already abroad

Tags: insurance, business-travel

I am in the USA from the UK on business and have used the opportunity to take some holiday in the US before the work related part of the trip. There was a mix-up before I travelled and I was mistakenly told by an administrator in my company that I would be covered by the business's travel insurance for the whole trip, but now while already in the US I have been informed that in fact I am only covered for the part that is directly business. I didn't buy insurance before I travelled because of this and so now I am in the US without travel insurance. Can I still purchase travel insurance now I have already begun the trip?

Comment: the question could be edited to remove the part about recommending any particular provider, and just answer the "can insurance be purchased for travelers who have started their travel?" or "purchasing travel insurance abroad"

Comment: Voting to reopen following the edit suggested by @EdmundYeung99.

Answer (score 5):

A couple from the UK have a [blog post dedicated to travel insurance for digital nomads](http://www.neverendingvoyage.com/travel-insurance-already-travelling-digital-nomads/).  They share some tips and make some recommendations (note they are affiliate links).

> It was difficult to find travel insurance policies that can be bought
>   when you are already travelling but we did manage to find a few
>   options and now always make sure we’re insured.

So yes it is possible to get travel insurance while already travelling, it may cost more and offer different levels of cover.  But shop around to see what level of cover suits you.

I suggest you perform a search for "travel insurance while abroad" to get a list of possible providers.  Then you can compare coverage and prices.  Also search for reviews to see if anything negative appears (for example blog posts of travellers having a bad experience with them).

Answer (score -1):

I had good luck with [Allianz Global](https://www.allianztravelinsurance.com/) but... buying insurance after you already started on your trip?  I don't think that is going to fly.  Kind of like telling the roulette croupier, "Oh, yeah, that was the number I *meant* to put my money on."

Call them and ask.

Comment: Not really a good analogy, because the insurance policy will cover you for a particular period.  They won't cover you for things that have happened in the past but they can certainly cover you for the future.

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 indeed, if the price structure includes coverage for flight cancellation, the company would come out ahead in this case, since the probability of the first flight being cancelled is zero: the traveler has already taken that flight and is already in the US.

Comment: You guys are being very, very optimistic.  If you apply for travel insurance after your trip is underway, the underwriting is going to assume you are standing outside the emergency room with a sucking chest wound.

Comment: My bank advertises with that you can get a travel insurance when you have already left the house having forgotten to arrange it before leaving. and indeed they do start the insurance the moment you want, also on the day you buy it.  I would just call, or have someone call from home, your normal travel insurance or theirs, and explain, if asked, that through misunderstanding you are abroad without insurance.

Comment: @Willeke -- that moment?  Why does anybody buy insurance in advance, instead of just waiting until they have a loss and then buy it?  (I bet they get extremely suspicious if you file a claim in the first few days of coverage.)  OP, given the above, it sounds like there are at least some companies willing to write a policy even after the trip has commenced.  Start calling around.

Comment: In travel insurance it is quite common, at least here, to buy it shortly before travel. Specially for last minute travel and for change of plan travel. Recently I bought two travel insurance policies (over the phone) and one was only days before leaving home. The guy of the company just wished my a good travel.

Comment: @Malvolio Insurance will not cover you for the whole trip, only from the point at which you buy the insurance

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 -- the insurance company does not employ agents to follow you around.  They don't know when you got sick, they only know when you went to the hospital.  If you get sick Monday, buy insurance Tuesday, and go to the hospital on Wednesday, the insurer is on the hook for a guaranteed loss.

Comment: @Malvolio yes, but such a scenario is probably not covered under the fine print.  You still need to make a claim and submit your evidence which they may very well deny.  Also if you lie, its called fraud.

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 -- it's certainly _not_ covered; it's called a "pre-existing condition".  The problem is, how can they check?

Answer (score -1):

I bought a policy from [Globelink](https://www.globelink.co.uk) when I was already abroad and realized I forgot to take out insurance. They used to provide this option only via phone calls but this year they announced it can be bought as any other policy online on their website.

Comment: Welcome to TSE.  Are you affiliated in any way with the company? Please disclose or disclaim that in the body of the answer, or it will be deleted as spam.